# post by taxonomy not showing at all in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Newbie here,

I'm trying to display the list of my post depends on the category. But it doesn't display my post. I tried the different type of array, but no luck. I named my page taxonomy-blog_category.php

I call the page via site.com/blog_category/category

here's my current code and I know I'm so close but can't figure it out.

Here is the array:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php $ctr = 1;
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $custom_args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'blog_post',
        'orderby'    => 'date',
        'order'      => 'DESC',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'paged'          => $paged,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'blog-category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array('business','people','technology'),
            ),
         ),
      );
```

Here is how I display the post

```
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_args ); ?>
<?php if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
     <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
         <div class="content-container">
             <div class="wrap">
                 <figure class="tint t2">
                    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>"  width="317px" height="240">
                 </figure>
             </div>
             <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
             <h3>By <?php the_field('author'); ?> | <span><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span></h3>
             <?php $content = get_field('content'); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 200, '...');?>
         <div class="read-more-btn">
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">read more</a>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>

 <?php $ctr++; endwhile; ?>
```

I Don't know if this is necessary but here's my code for pagination:

```
<div class="pagination-holder">
    <ul class="pagination">
         <?php
             if (function_exists(custom_pagination)) {
                  custom_pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages,"",$paged);
             }
        ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php else:  ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>   
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this a custom post type you made called 'blog_post' or are you just trying to get your regular posts?

Comment: @Tom its a custom post with a slug of blog_post

Comment: I'd suggest removing the tax_query portion and seeing if posts show up. From the outside creating a post type for blog posts seems a bit odd.

Comment: @Tom after removing the tax_query, it will display all blogs, but i need is the post only by single category, for example is, the blogs only from business

Comment: Are you logging the errors? Anything coming up there?

Comment: after debugging with the tax_query, it say's Sorry, no posts matched your criteria. Which is from my pagination

Comment: and there's no error in console

Comment: if you've got content that is in those categories, you could try expanding your tax_query into multiple arguments and adding them one by one.